# How to avoid Page Reload Resend-Data message with PHP

Tags: php

I am relatively new to PHP, so my apologies if the answer is trivial. Lol

I wrote a simple Contact Us email form (actually a WordPress page-template file). All the code is in one file.

After the user submits the form and the email is sent, the file generates a Thank You message.

If the user reloads the Thank You page, they are prompted to "Resend the Form Data," which is why I am asking this question.

My question: How do I avoid the prompt to resend the form data and still keep all of my code (including the Thank You data) in one file?

EDIT: I've seen folks use headers( Location: ), but I don't think that will work for if I want to keep all my code in one file.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies! I'll give everything a look-over tomorrow morning. If you happen upon this question and see an answer you agree with, give it an Up-Vote so I know! =)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could redirect to a different query.

```
header("Location: ?page=thankyou");
```

Then, you don't even need to check if the POST data was sent. Just display the thank you page if page is equal to thank you.

Comment: Looks good. I'm wondering, is there any more code necessary to throw the header(), or is it really that simple?

Comment: For those interested, I've been told I should include the full url in the Location and also include an exit; after throwing the header().

Comment: It was the best answer I found in stackoverflow! @TylerCarter thank you very much.

Comment: There should almost definitely be an `exit;` after the `header("Location: ...")`, otherwise PHP will continue executing whatever code comes after it.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me, it can be put anywhere in html file not just beginning like header() function:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST)){
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.location = window.location.href;
    </script>
<?php } ?>
```

I placed it into prevent_resend.php and then included it after the postdata processing was done.

```
// ... save data from $_POST to DB
include('prevent_resend.php');
// ... do some other stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to post the form and show the thank you message. This way the browser never leaves the page.

Answer (score 0):

Even with a header('Location: xxx'); you can still redirect it to the same page, and either set a url parameter or a session variable to distinguish what should be shown.

Answer (score 0):

Although I question your requirement to have all the code in one file (why couldn't you separate it, and use `require_once` to include shared library code?), the `header('Location:')` technique is still completely valid.  Simply do:

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/path/to/my-one-file-of-code.php?thankyou=1');
```

Then, in your file, you can have:

```
if (isset($_GET['thankyou']) && $_GET['thankyou']) {
    // Do whatever it is you do to thank the visitor.
}
```

Comment: The second parameter will generate an Error for every other page.

Comment: @Chacha102: The second `$_GET` isn't evaluated because `&&` is lazy - it can't generate an error.

Comment: to make @toomuchphp comment more complete/clear, php attempts optimization, for example it evaluates only parts of if's if that is possible. for example if ($foo && $bar) will check first foo, and if its false, than it knows, it will no matter what not match condition so it skips rest. same goes for OR, thats why you can find at some places code like connected_to_database OR die. PHP checks if first condition is enough to say whole statement is true. if first condition is true, result will be allways true, so second part will be skipped. Though btw, proper way would be if (@$_GET["thankyou"]).

Comment: @GallAnnonim It is absolutely not appropriate to use `@$_GET['thankyou']`. The `@` just suppresses errors from appearing. Always write code that explicitly protects against the error occurring in the first place. In this case, check whether the property exists, and then use that property. Relying on `@` can hide all sorts of problems including other errors, which would also get suppressed.

Comment: Thats true that @ is suppresing errors, but conditions allways work, and it allows for shorter and more readable code, which I consider a main thing. I use @ only in places where I explicitely expect warn and Im sure nothing will broken if that happenes. but that may be just me.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
header("Location: #");
```