# Reset the form data on unload

Tags: php, forms

I'm using this code:

```
if(isset($_POST['btitle'])) {
    if(count($errors) > 0) {
        foreach($errors as $error)
            $errContent .= "<li>".$error;
        echo notification(
            $errContent,
            FALSE,
            "The following errors were encountered:"
        ) . "<div style='margin-bottom: 10px;'></div>";
    }
    else {
        echo notification(
            "<li>New form added!",
            TRUE,
            "Success:"
        ) . "<div style='margin-bottom: 10px;'></div>";
    }
}
```

When I type something in the input named 'btitle' and hit the submit button, everything is fine, until I refresh the page - it should loose the data and start again after refreshing, but it keep saying "Success:" even if the 'btitle' input is **empty**.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to redirect the user to the same page and loose the post data.

```
header("Location: file.php?success=true");//or ?errors[]=blabla
exit();
```

now, in the same page (file.php) you need to:

```
if(isset($_GET['success']) && $_GET['success'] == true){
    //handle true
}else if(/* here you can ask about errors or what ever */){

}
```

BTW, if you don't do it, the entire submitting form will be act again like you resubmit it.
for instance, if you insert data to the database, it will be insert over and over again when you refresh the page,  so if you redirect as suggested, you loose the posted data and now you can show the errors or success.

Answer (score 0):

When you hit refresh, your browser resends POST data to the page. This question has been asked many times, for instance **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2666882/how-to-avoid-resending-data-on-refresh-in-php)** and **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290745/how-to-avoid-page-reload-resend-data-message-with-php)**. Take a look at the answers to some of those questions to get an idea of what you can do.