# Best way for form validation in PHP and JS

Tags: php, javascript, forms, validation

I was wondering what actually the best way for a solid form validation is.

JavaScript does a quite good jon, but it is not a base for a solid validation, because it can be manipulated or even disabled.

If you check the data with PHP and re-populate a form when an error occurrs, there are several problems with a post form.

- If the form is displayed without redirecting, then F5 will show a confirm box if the user wants to re-send the data, this is not really beautiful.
- If the user gets redirected to the form again, the data must be submitted by `GET` or `POST`. With `POST`, there is again the F5-Problem as mentioned above. With `GET`, a problem exists when transferring values with a `&` inside (PHP guesses another parameter after the sign)
- A third way would be to store the data in a database, e.g. SUBMITTRIALS or something like that. But then you'd actually have to clear the data after redirecting.

Another problem comes along with re-populating of the form itself: A code like this:

```
echo "<input type='text' value='".$val."' />";
```

is quite a problem if the variable `$val` contains a value containing apostrophes, this generates invalid HTML.

As you can see, there are quite much possibilities of failure in a form validation scenario. What would be the most reliable way to handle form-validation as described at top?

Comment: you would normally do `htmlspecialchars(..)` and not echo $val directly. That would be a great XSS problem! Also you could not use a Database but sessions!

Comment: You have outlined the problems well. There is no silver bullet, each of these problems has to be dealt with individually: you can HTML encode your variables to avoid the apostrophe problem; you can try to pass some validation information from the server to the client so that the same validation rules are being used in both places, but it's never going to be neat. And I don't think you're ever going to get around the POST problem - that's just the way HTTP works.

Comment: Bear in mind that HTML5 forms afford built-in validation in the browser http://24ways.org/2009/have-a-field-day-with-html5-forms/. If this is enough for you, you can just set the field types correctly, let the browser take care of the client-side, and then you just focus on the server-side validation. Makes your job easier.

Comment: @RobinWinslow this is a nice approach, but if the user makes a mistake, it must be correctly communicated, maybe with a little help and a localizated text. So I want to create my own way how to show the error (red text, red border, alert box, etc). HTML5 does a very nice job for some small forms, but with bigger forms you should take care by yourself.

Comment: You could also store the data via a SESSION cookie, instead of just relying on POST and GET

Comment: @androidavid what's the problem if the user just gets re-populated _his own form_, so all he would be able to inject can just injure himself... or am I wrong here?

Comment: @Florian: This depends on the whole architecture. In default case you're right. But in worst case: If the architecture is bad you could redirect the session id (of course you would do have to dome some other cracking on the victims side, but this can be done by exploits) and then do XSS. Btw: You should also consider that `<` could cause the site to break which for a normal user would be really irritating :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Server side languages are the only way to validate your form. You can store your form data in session or cookies for the same purpose. You can flush them once you are done with your validation. If you are having a problem with the quotes in your data then you can use PHP inbuilt function `addslashes()` and `stripslashes()` to avoid them.

Answer (score 1):

Your three main points, one by one:

1. Yes, that's correct and no, it's not very elegant. But as you said: redirecting solves that issue. So redirect.
2. Nope, converting the ampersand to `&amp;` shouldn't pose a problem
3. Why use a database to store data like that? What is wrong with sessions? Or, if needs must: a cookie?

In resuming: redirect to avoid the confirmation box, use a session if you need to store some submitted data server-side and convert ampersands to their html entities and you're all set. 
Converting `&` can be achieved like so:

```
var tmpDiv = document.createElement('div');
tmpDiv.innerText = '&';
var entity = tmpDiv.innerHTML;//returns &amp;
```

Comment: Well, this is actually a workaround, isn't it? 
I know about the JavaScript function encode() and PHPs urlencode() which are also a quite good solution for `GET`-Parameters

Comment: JavaScripts `encodeURI` doesn't convert ampersands to html entities, because it's considered valid, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I have some solutions for you.

1. You need to redirect the user to the same page and loose the post data.

   ```
   header("Location: samefile.php?success=true");//or ?errors[]=blabla
   exit();

   if(isset($_GET['success']) && $_GET['success'] == true){
       //handle true
   }else if(/* here you can ask about errors or what ever */){

   }
   ```

   In this way you can avoid re-sending data on refresh.
2. Use $_SESSION to store data instead of database.

Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: ...You are redirecting every time you load the file to itself? This is an infinite loop...
But storing the data in the session is actually a nice approach. The bad possibility is just the point at re-populating the form, as @androidavid mentioned in his comment.

Comment: @Florian Sorry. But that's why I gave exit(). And I guess this way you can actually avoid [re-sending](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290745/how-to-avoid-page-reload-resend-data-message-with-php?lq=1) data on refresh.

Comment: Did you try that solution? Cause for myself I am either confused or dont believe that this would work

Answer (score -2):

I am using the jquery form validator, and that works quite well.

in your head tag:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/media/js/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/media/js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#commentform" ).validate();
  });
</script>
```

And then use a form like this:

```
  <form id="commentform" action="/index/addcomment" method="POST">

    <p>
      <input type="text" name="Name" id="name" value="" size="22" class="required" minlength="3">
      <label for="name"><em>*</em><?= _("Name") ?></label>
    </p>

    <p>
      <input type="text" name="EMail" id="email" value="" size="22" class="required email">
      <label for="email"><em>*</em><?= _("EMail") ?> <?= _("(will not be published)") ?></label>
    </p>

    <p>
      <input type="text" name="Url" id="url" value="" size="22">
      <label for="url"><?= _("Website") ?></label>
    </p>

    <p>
      <textarea name="Content" id="comment" cols="100%" rows="10" class="required" minlength="5"></textarea>
    </p>

    <p>
      <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" tabindex="5" value="Submit Comment">
      <input type="hidden" name="BlogId" value="<?= $this->model->BlogId ?>" />
    </p>

  </form>
```

More info: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Comment: I think the OP knows about this sort of solution. He mentions that this approach has the weakness of not being verified server-side. It looks like he's looking for a server+client solution.

Comment: @RobinWinslow thats correct. The clientside validation is no problem, I usually tend to realize it completely by myself.

Comment: Ahh .. ok. I put the $_POST vars in my model, and then get the model posted back to the form. When putting something in the database, I use parameter binding. Sometimes in conjunction with typecasting. And of course, my business rules apply to the model.

Comment: Also, this thread is not tagged with jQuery, please only post pure JS answers.

Comment: Well, if jQuery proved a solution to the problems mentioned above, a jQuery answer was quite welcome ;)

Comment: @CharlesJohnThompsonIII don't you think it's okay to suggest jQuery as a solution even if it wasn't asked for? I agree this answer isn't particularly helpful, but in general it seems fine to suggest extra tools like jQuery if they would make the solution considerably simpler.

Comment: @RobinWinslow: I'm sorry, but I can get really worked up about this. Whenever I ask a JS question I have to explicitly say that I don't want jQ answers, or else I'll be showered with them. Tags are meant to organize questions _and_ specify the type of answers you expect. There's no point in using the _MySQL_ tag, asking how to do something, if all you get are answerls like: _MSSQL_ has function X for that. The same analogy holds for _PHP_ tags, answerd by _ZendFW_ has a component you can use... and for JavaScript questions answered with `assuming jQuery...`

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem okay but you could explicitly say in your question "I don't want to use jQuery". For pedestrian JavaScript problems, jQuery *does* usually provide the neatest solution. Exactly as Florian says "jQuery answer was quite welcome" - I think this would apply to most people wanting JavaScript solutions.

Comment: @RobinWinslow: I still disagree: not tagging your question jQuery should be interpreted as a request for a JavaScript answer and vice-versa. If I don't use the jQuery tag, and post pure JS, I shouldn't have to explicitly say `No jQuery, no mootools, no prototype.js, no...`. If the OP is willing to accept jQuery he can always specify that either by tagging, or by saying so. Like implied globals in JS are bad, implied tags are _EVIL_, IMHO. I guess we'll have to agree to disagree, and I'm sorry if I came across a bit blunt in my previous comment, no hard feelings, though. :)

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem we should really take this to chat, but one final point: if I ask a question, I probably don't know all the tools / libraries out there that might help me solve it. I want people to offer me a range of solutions. I can always reject ones I don't want. I really don't want someone to deliberately not tell me about a library that could solve my problem more neatly just because I haven't explicitly asked for it.

Comment: I'm on the JS chat if you want, but I feel as though this has the makings of another pointless discussion. If you're open to libs/toolkits just say so. Perhaps you could suggest a tag _toolkit/lib_ to signal that... Perhaps I'm alone in this, but I personally don't like it that jQuery is assumed. Using it as default answer is one of the main causes for a lot of (pardon my French) nitwits thinking it's either a new language or std JS syntax. Result: More and more questions like _Why is "$" undefined?_. Though I respect your opinion, I don't share it. That's all as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: @RobinWinslow in response to your response to my response of your solution: no.